# How to configure logging in Quartz.NET scheduler

Tags: logging, quartz.net

How I can configure logging to a text file in Quartz.NET scheduler? Shall I achieve it by using only Common.Logging.dll or I need log4net also?

Comment: I got the answer from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001613/logging-with-quartz-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch from Log4Net to NLog in Quartz.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569936/how-do-i-switch-from-log4net-to-nlog-in-quartz-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Common Logging and NLog as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569936/how-do-i-switch-from-log4net-to-nlog-in-quartz-net/6570161#6570161).