# Quartz.Net Jobs to Log File

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm currently creating a scheduler using Quartz.net with the CronSchedule. I'm wanting to send information regarding the 'Jobs' such as time executed and finished to a .txt file or something which logs the information, however I don't know how to approach this.

Any help?

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594341/how-to-configure-logging-in-quartz-net-scheduler

Comment: Try using log4net to create the log files you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use log4net, I suggest to log separate for each Job.

Before to start scheduler:

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(location + ".config"));
```

In each class that extends IJob (so, in each Job):

```
var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("TestJobLogger");
```

Where obviously `"TestJobLogger"` is different for each Job.

In the `App.config` insert this, one `<logger>` and one `<appender>` for each Job you have:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    ...
    <log4net>
    <appender name="AppenderTestJob" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd-HH" />
        <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\PathToSaveFile\" />
        <datePattern value="'test.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] [%-5p] (%c) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
    </root>
    <logger name="TestJobLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="AppenderTestJob" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

Now, you can log simply with `logger.Debug("TESTTTTTT");`.

Comment: This creates a dependency on Log4Net. How would you inject an ILogger?