# All jobs misfire for unknown reason; works fine with RAMJobStore but not with MS SQL

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET in an application for the Microsoft Bot Framework. I'm debugging it on the local machine (although the database is still on Azure).

For some reason all jobs misfire and they wouldn't fire again, even though I tried various .WithMisfire... options.

I set the job to run every 15-20 seconds for testing. I've set a breakpoint on the first line of the Execute() in my job class, but it never reaches that point. So all jobs fail without even reaching Execute().

I can see the jobs and triggers being created in the database, with the `TRIGGER_STATE = WAITING`. After they reach their appointed execution time, the state changes to `ERROR`.

Here's my code to launch the scheduler:

```
public static IScheduler StartAndGetScheduler()
        {
            NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";

            properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=*************.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=*************;" +
                "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***********;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";


            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            scheduler = sf.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            return scheduler;
        }
```

Here's the code that schedules the job (for testing):

```
        try {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int dice = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            string jobName = "job719-" + dice.ToString();

            LogSchedulerStatus(scheduler, activity);

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BotSchedulerJob>()
                    .WithIdentity(jobName, "group1")
                    .Build();

            currentJob = job;

            int dice2 = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            string triggerName = "trigger719-" + dice2.ToString();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(triggerName, "group1")
                .StartAt(Quartz.DateBuilder.FutureDate(15, IntervalUnit.Second))
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(20)
                    .WithRepeatCount(2)
                    .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNowWithRemainingCount()) 
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            LogSchedulerStatus(scheduler, activity);
        }
        // no exceptions - all works fine, jobs are in the database
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendReplyToUser(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n\n", activity);
        }
```

And here is the job itself:

```
public class BotSchedulerJob : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            //breakpoint here never reached in debugger
            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));
            IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            newMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
            newMessage.From = new ChannelAccount("********");
            newMessage.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(false, "8a684db8");
            newMessage.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("********");
            newMessage.Text = "This is a reminder.";
            connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)newMessage);
        }
    }
```

After I try to schedule a job, the last lines in the log are:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll
Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Finally, if I configure Quartz to use RAMJobStore, it works fine and triggers the jobs successfully.

Comment: I suggest you [enable Quartz.Net logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001613/logging-with-quartz-net)

Comment: Thanks @stuartd, I'm getting     Exception thrown: 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' in Quartz.dll

Comment: Have you tried using the memory store instead of the ADO store? Is the connection string correct? Are the correct tables present int the database? Does the database user have the correct permissions. The message supplied by JobPersistenceException will likely tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @JackHughes unfortunately I don't know how to get the exception message. I'm just using this standard line from the documentation for logging: Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter { Level = Common.Logging.LogLevel.Debug };

Comment: @JackHughes the memory store works fine; the connection string is likely correct because new records appear in the database whenever I try to schedule a job. I assume this means the tables are correct too. I can access the database under this user from MS SQL Management Studio and read/edit records.