# How to configure ninject with Quartz.net and log4net

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, log4net, quartz.net

I try to make `quartz` and `log4net` work with `ninject`.

`Ninject` with `log4net` (without `quartz`) works perfect.

But when I use with `Quartz`, jobs executed but logger not working. (empty console)

Below is `Ninject` configuration:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(x => LogManager.GetLogger(x.Request.Target != null
                        ? x.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType
                        : x.Request.Service));

kernel.Bind<IScheduler>().ToMethod(x =>
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    var sched = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
    sched.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(kernel);
    return sched;
});
```

and ninjetJobFactory:

```
class NinjectJobFactory : SimpleJobFactory
{
    readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectJobFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        try
        {
            // this will inject dependencies that the job requires
            return (IJob)this._kernel.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format("Problem while instantiating job '{0}' from the NinjectJobFactory.", bundle.JobDetail.Key), e);
        }
    }
}
```

I Used [this article](https://knightcodes.com/.net/2016/08/15/dependency-injection-for-quartz-net.html) to make `Quarts` work with ninject.

I made [simple working example](https://github.com/kadyrkulovr/QuartzTest/tree/master/QuartzTest), you can download it from github for testing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: 1. I use console appender, and console is empty. 2. I put breakpoint in my SimpleJob class and debug line by line

Comment: Yes file not created when i use WithQuartz.

Comment: I guess method Execute invoked by the scheduler, i Don't call it manually

Comment: Sorry, maybe i don't understand you correctly, I added for test Console.writeLine("test"), and job works, displays text every 3 second

Comment: I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001613/logging-with-quartz-net) they use `common.logging`. I think I should try it.

Comment: Ok i downloaded and ran it and can reproduce the problem. checking it out.

Comment: When I uncomment withoutquartz and have both methods run then the withquartz works. investigating

Comment: If I resolve the logger manually and log any message before starting scheduler, everything works as expected.

Comment: Ok even if I do not log a message, Once I manually resolve `ILog` then it works as expected. Seems to be something with how the logger is resolved in the factory

Comment: Ok, it works now, that's enough for me, you can post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I made some refactored improvements based on the example project. Take a look.

Comment: Quartz uses LibLog which resolves active logging implementation on first call to logging methods. So if you don't have it configured when Quarrz methods are first called, no-op will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While investigating the issue I realized that by simply resolving the `ILog` from the kernel before resolving the scheduler seemed to work. As to the reason why I was a bit uncertain.

I did notice however that the version of Quartz being used has an asynchronous API so had to make some changes during my investigation of the problem.

In the comments of the link documentation, it was suggested to refactor to new async API  syntax

```
kernel.Bind<Task<IScheduler>>().ToMethod(async _ => {
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    var sched = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    sched.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(kernel);
    return sched;
});
```

I improved on this by creating a service that tales advantage of the async API when starting the scheduler.

```
public interface IService {
    Task Start();
}

public class Service : IService {
    private readonly IJobFactory jobFactory;
    private readonly ILog log;
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory;

    public Service(IJobFactory jobFactory, ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory, ILog log) {
        this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
        this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public async Task Start() {
        IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create()
           .OfType<SimpleJob>()
           .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(3)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        await scheduler.Start();

        log.Debug("Scheduler started");
    }
}
```

I created a bootstrapper and used the `NinjectModule`s to properly organize dependency injections

```
public class Bootstrapper {
    public IKernel Init() {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        kernel.Bind<IServiceProvider>().ToConstant(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
}

public class LoggingModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<ILog>()
            .ToMethod(x => LogManager.GetLogger(
                x.Request.Target != null ? x.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType : x.Request.Service)
            );
    }
}

public class QuartzModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IJobFactory>().To<NinjectJobFactory>();
        Bind<ISchedulerFactory>().To<StdSchedulerFactory>();
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
    }
}

class NinjectJobFactory : IJobFactory {
    readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public NinjectJobFactory(IServiceProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler) {
        IJobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
        Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
        try {
            // this will inject any dependencies that the job requires
            var value = (IJob)provider.GetService(jobType);
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format("Problem while instantiating job '{0}' from the NinjectJobFactory.", bundle.JobDetail.Key), e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the job factory to destroy/cleanup the job if needed. 
    /// No-op when using SimpleJobFactory.
    /// </summary>
    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) {
        var disposable = job as IDisposable;
        disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

With that modification and updating the main program accordingly

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        var kernel = bootstrapper.Init();

        WithQuartz(kernel).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static Task WithQuartz(IKernel kernel) {
        var service = kernel.Get<IService>();
        return service.Start();
    }
}
```

everything seems to work as expected.